# Capybara check value of submit buttons on has_content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Right now I have a webpage that displays a list with the audio queue for upcoming songs. Each list item is actually it's own form with a submit button that has it's value set to a specific songs title.

I'm trying to write a feature test that checks the page to make sure it has the content of each of the songs that have been added to the queue, the problem is that capybara doesn't seem to 'see' the value of submit buttons when using page.has_content. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Please show sample HTML

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your HTML has things like

```
<input type="submit" value="Song name"/>
```

then you'll want to use the `has_button?`/`assert_button`/`have_button` methods.  This is because `has_content?` checks against the content of text children of elements which the above `input` element doesn't have.  By default `has_button?` (and associated) will match on the id, value, or title attribute of a submit input but you can specify a specific one if it is critical.  In RSpec this would look like

```
expect(page).to have_button('Song name')
```

or if the song name might collide with an element id and you wanted to be 100% sure it was only matching value you could do

```
expect(page).to have_button(value: 'something')
```